# How do you run two instances of firefox using threads in java webdriver

Tags: java, multithreading, webdriver

I am a basic java user and currently I am trying to create an automated test case that tests my email functions. So what I have in mind is:

1. Using selenium webdriver in java the program creates a thread that starts a browser, goes to google email, creates a test email and sends it to my yahoo email account. After that it sleeps indefinitely till it receives a message or signal to send another email.
2. While that is being done, another thread is being created to go to yahoo email account and monitor new incoming email. Once it receives an email, a message or signal is sent to the first thread to send another email.
3. The whole process will repeat itself for a total of two more times, so there will be three email exchanged between gmail and yahoo email.

So far the code is this. I am not really sure how to progress from here. More specifically I am not sure how to add the threads in there so that the two instances will run concurrently.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class multi_test {

    public WebDriver driver1;
    protected WebDriver driver2;
    public String baseUrl1;
    public String baseUrl2;
    protected StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    public class setup1 implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            driver1.get(baseUrl1);
        }
    }

    public class setup2 implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            driver2.get(baseUrl2);
        }
    }
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl1 = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(driver1);
        driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl2 = "https://google.com";
        driver2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testing1() throws Exception {
        driver1.get(baseUrl1);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //driver1.quit();
        //driver2.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any help will be more than appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you need two separate threads for that?

Answer (score 0):

Why use threads?
Not better prepare two tests? Send and receive? 
One sends mail - passed ? good we can proceed to next one
Receiver will wait for an email, checking in interval for example 30 in next XX minutes or so?

U can run it in TestNG for repeat 3 times?

Btw. good post why don't automate gmail :)))

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selenium-users/8jR6Fw5ndxU/7peVDuzkNN4J